# Angular with Play (Scala): ng-include references

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework, reference, angularjs-ng-include

### Situation

I started an app with [**Playframework**](https://www.playframework.com/) ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)) and [**AngularJS**](https://angularjs.org/) `v1.3`.

*(Exactly the template* [*Play Silhouette Angular Seed*](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed)*)*

### Goal

Loading difference templates using **ng-include** or a **directive**.

### Problem

Always that I put a reference in Angular code,  it doesn't work.

*Example:*

```
<div ng-include="'/tpl.html'"></div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
   Content of the template.
</script>
```

*Result: **works!!***

*Now, if I put the template `tpl.html` in a file in the same directory:*

```
<div ng-include="'tpl.html'"></div>
```

*Result: **Doesn't work!!** (And in other directories, I tried all the possible routes...)*

The same problem occurs in directives, if I put the template inside the directory it works well, but if I try to put in another file it doesn't work.

### Question

I used Angular in other projects and never occurs something like this. I think that this happens because Scala (language of Playframework) needs to be compiled and the files `.scala.html` are converted in `.html`.

- How can I create some templates `.html` and then with **ng-include**
  put the correct reference?

Comment: template file path should be relative to your index page.

Comment: Just I tried this again and doesn't work. `ng-include="'view1.html'"` and  `view.html` file in the same directory that `index.html`...

Comment: `view1.html` sorry, not view.html.

Comment: What play version is it? 2.4?

Comment: 2.1 I think. Is the default version from the template that I used: https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed

Comment: 1) For your reference, the template uses Play 2.4.2. 2) In the example project, the views are served from `/views/*.html`.

Comment: solved!! Thanks for all man! Finally the same that first comment that I did, but changed `ng-include="'view1.html'"` to `ng-include="'./view1.html'"` !! And in the same directory to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root directory is the same that `index.html`file (*path: `ui/app`*).

If the file `view1.html` is in the path `ui/app`, the **ng-include** will be like this:

```
<div ng-include="'./view1.html'"></div>
```

Because `ui/app` is the **root path**.